# Room lighting using LED strips only

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

We're starting renovating our flat and are kinda lost in terms of lighting.  The flat is well a flat... made of hard concrete on all sides. Nothing in straight especially the ceiling so we need to cover the whole ceiling with drywall. The size of an example room is 5.3m x 3.5m with 2.6m height. The problem is that the top of the window opening is just 18cm from the ceiling so we can't make deeper ceilings. I could make lighting like below [image]
but it feels too much and I'm not sure if lighting would be sufficient in the middle 2m*3.5m part of the room. My spouse really like LED lighting with the LED strips like:
[image]
However I can't find any reliable information whether rooms of this size could be illuminated using only led strips?  Sure enough that would look a lot cleaner since all the ceiling would be flat, with the LED strips sunk into the drywall with an opal cover that would make the strip look uniform. My problem with this is that I can't find any information or guidance how to place LED strips to achieve an acceptable lighting across the room.

Any tips?

Comment: U have switch outlets on the ceiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most architectural designers recommend a mix of lighting types (ambient, task, accent) to give a room balance. You should research design *ideas*.

I would think that your LED strips would be used for *ambient* lighting, and as such there are some standards to follow regarding minimum lumens for a particular room type (like, 20 lumens per square foot). Since you already have specific strips in mind, calculate total lumens needed and design your strip layout to meet that. Then you can add accent and task lighting depending on room function and layout.